# find which polygon lat/lon fall within (in python)

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

Is there any way do do something similar in python what I had been doing in R?

```
library(maps)
library(rgdal)
mp = 'gadm41_USA_shp' #from gadm.org
mp = rgdal::readOGR(mp)
mymap = maps::SpatialPolygons2map(mp, namefield="ISO_1")
map.where(mymap, y = 40.725959, x = -73.978544)
#[1] "US-NY:88"
```

Link to shapefile: https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/shp/gadm41_USA_shp.zip

In python I can read in the shape file, but how do I go about checking where a point falls?

```
import geopandas as gpd
shp = gpd.read_file("gadm41_USA_1.shp")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, GeometryCollection, Polygon, mapping


shp = gpd.read_file('gadm41_USA_1.shp')
pt = Point(-73.978544, 40.725959)

print(shp.loc[shp['geometry'].contains(pt), 'ISO_1'])

32    US-NY
Name: ISO_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can I recommend that you change your last line to: `print(shp.loc[shp['geometry'].contains(pt), 'ISO_1'])`? This way, the row/column indexing is unambiguous